# conditionally Replace string in a Pandas series with another string

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Take the below example. To replace one string in one particular column I have done this and it worked fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'data1': range(6),
                   'data2': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1']},
                   columns = ['key', 'data1', 'data2'])

  key  data1 data2
0   A      0    A1
1   B      1    B1
2   C      2    C1
3   A      3    A1
4   B      4    B1
5   C      5    C1



df['data2']= df['data2'].str.strip().str.replace("A1","Bad")

  key  data1 data2
0   A      0    Bad
1   B      1    B1
2   C      2    C1
3   A      3    Bad
4   B      4    B1
5   C      5    C1
```

Q(1) How can we conditionally replace one string? Meaning that, in column `data2`, I would like to replace `A1` but only `if "key==A" and "data1">1`.  How can I do that?

Q(2) Can the conditional replacement be applied to multiple replacement (i.e., replacing `A1 and A2` at the same time with "Bad" but only under similar conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy` and a `regex`-based replacement to cover `A1, A2` and more. if we extend your data to include an example with `A3`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
                   'data1': range(7),
                   'data2': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A3']},
                   columns=['key', 'data1', 'data2'])

df['data2'] = np.where((df['key'] == 'A') & (df['data1'] > 1),
                       df['data2'].str.replace(r'A\d+','Bad'),
                       df['data2'])
```

This returns:

```
  key  data1 data2
0   A      0    A1
1   B      1    B1
2   C      2    C1
3   A      3   Bad
4   B      4    B1
5   C      5    C1
6   A      6   Bad
```

Answer (score 3):

I think need filter column in both sides with replace only for filtered rows:

```
mask = (df['key']=="A") &  (df['data1'] > 1)
df.loc[mask, 'data2']= df.loc[mask, 'data2'].str.strip().str.replace("A1","Bad")  

print (df)
  key  data1 data2
0   A      0    A1
1   B      1    B1
2   C      2    C1
3   A      3   Bad
4   B      4    B1
5   C      5    C1
```

If need multiple replace use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'data1': range(6),
                   'data2': ['A1', 'A2', 'C1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1']},
                   columns = ['key', 'data1', 'data2'])

mask = (df['key']=="A") &  (df['data1'] > 0)
df.loc[mask, 'data2']= df.loc[mask, 'data2'].str.strip().replace({"A1":"Bad", "A2":'Bad1'})
```

Or use regex:

```
df.loc[mask, 'data2']= df.loc[mask, 'data2'].str.strip().str.replace(r'^A.*',"Bad")


print (df)
  key  data1 data2
0   A      0    A1
1   A      1  Bad1
2   C      2    C1
3   A      3   Bad
4   B      4    B1
5   C      5    C1
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to extend the example above in the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'data1': range(6),
                   'data2': ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1']},
                   columns = ['key', 'data1', 'data2'])  

mask = (df['data1'] > 1)
df.loc[mask, 'data2']= df.loc[mask, 'data2'].str.strip().str.replace("A1",df['key']) 

  key  data1 data2
0   A      0    A1
1   B      1    B1
2   C      2   NaN
3   A      3   NaN
4   B      4   NaN
5   C      5   NaN
```

I am very surprised by the answer I thought the content of data2 would be replaced by content of column "key" (at the condition data1>1). any idea?

Comment: Do you need `df.loc[mask, 'data2']= df.loc[mask].apply(lambda x: x['data2'].strip().replace('A1', x['key']), axis=1)` ?

Comment: @jezrael   ..thats exactly what I need...thank you and thank you again..... iam trying to apply it to my data and I get an error saying  "raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series key provided')
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided"

Comment: Hmmm, solution is same only data are changed?

Comment: Sometimes help `df.loc[mask.values, 'data2']= df.loc[mask.values]`, but without data hard to know.